# re-use of code for showing the active link of menu

Tags: html, css

code for creating menu in html

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="top"><a href="index.jsp" class="active_link"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Police Station</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li><a href="VPolicestation.jsp">Add New Station</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:searchVPS()">Update Station</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Police Officer</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li><a href="addOfficer.jsp">Add New Officer</a></li>
<li><a href="assignStation.jsp">Assign Station</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:searchOfficer()">Update Officer</a></li>
</ul>
</li>                                
<li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Report</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li><a href="#">Crime Report</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Citizen Report</a></li>
</ul>
</li>                                
<li class="top"><a href="logout.jsp" class="top_link"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**menu.css**

```
.bg {background: url(images/button4.gif);}
.menu {padding:0 0 0 32px; margin:0; list-style:none; height:40px; background:#fff url(images/button1a.gif) repeat-x; position:relative; font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif; }
.menu li.top {display:block; float:left; position:relative;}
.menu li a.top_link {display:block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:33px; color:#bbb; text-decoration:none; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; padding:0 0 0 12px; cursor:pointer;}
.menu li a.top_link span {float:left; font-weight:bold; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:40px;}
.menu li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:40px; background:url(images/down.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span.down {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}

.menu li:hover > a.top_link {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span.down {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}


.menu li a.active_link {display:block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:33px; color:#bbb; text-decoration:none; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; padding:0 0 0 12px; cursor:pointer;}
.menu li a.active_link span {float:left; font-weight:bold; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:40px;}
.menu li a.active_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:40px; background:url(images/down.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li > a.active_link {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li > a.active_link span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li > a.active_link span.down {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}

.menu table {border-collapse:collapse; width:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}

.menu a:hover {visibility:visible;}
.menu li:hover {position:relative; z-index:200;}

.menu ul, 
.menu :hover ul ul, 
.menu :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

.menu :hover ul.sub {left:2px; top:40px; right:2px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0; border:1px solid #999999; white-space:nowrap; width:150px; height:auto;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li {display:block; height:20px; position:relative; float:left; width:150px;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a {font-weight:normal;display:block; font-size:11px; height:20px; width:148px; line-height:20px; text-indent:5px; color:#000; text-decoration:none; border:3px solid #fff; border-width:0 0 0 3px;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a.fly {background:#fff url(images/arrow.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a:hover {background:#999999; color:#fff;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover {background:#999999 url(images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat; color:#fff;}
.menu :hover ul li:hover > a.fly {background:#999999 url(images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat; color:#fff;} 

.menu :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul
{left:90px; top:-4px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0; border:1px solid 999999; white-space:nowrap; width:93px; z-index:200; height:auto;}
```

in this code class **active_link** is used for showing the current page belongs to the particular menu option, and **top_link** class is used for showing simple form of menu. Then, class **down** is used for indicating the sub-link under the particular menu. Now, i want to show the current active menu for which the particular page is belonging.

**Ex :** if i'm in **addOfficer.jsp** page, then, **Police Officer** link should show the active.

To achieving this, i'm pasting the same code in each pages, and just changing  class name **top_link** to **active_link**. And, it is increasing the length of code. Need Help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance !!

Screenshot of menu.
[image: Screenshot of menu]

Comment: Why not add a second class i.e. `class="top_link active"` and change only what you need in the CSS. `.top_link.active { ... }`

Comment: can you please, show me what should i change in my code.. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Without pasting all of your code again. Assuming we want "Police Officer" tab to be the active one, we can add an 'active' class to the `a` tag:

```
<li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link active"><span class="down">Police Officer</span></a>
```

The CSS could be be something like that (making the hover and active states similar):

```
.menu li:hover a.top_link,
.menu li a.top_link:hover,
.menu li a.top_link.active {color:#000; background: url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat;}
.menu li:hover a.top_link span,
.menu li a.top_link:hover span,
.menu li a.top_link.active span {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li:hover a.top_link span.down,
.menu li a.top_link:hover span.down,
.menu li a.top_link.active span.down {background:url(images/button4.gif) no-repeat right top;}
```

As to the `active_link` CSS, it is no longer needed.
Notice I've combined the two hover states as well. Thought it would help you reuse even more styling code.